# How to show the entire number of records in the attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table

How do I show the entire number of records in an attribute table?  The number should be around 100k records, but it only loads 2k at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to click the "Go to last record" button, in ArcGIS it's called "End of table":

[image]

For large tables, it may take a minute to complete, but it will make the last record in the table the active one, and show you the total number of records in the table (assuming you don't have any definition queries active).

Comment: For *very* large tables it may take hours to complete (which is why the table is queried in chunks).

Answer (score 3):

A faster method for larger tables would be to use the [Get Count (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) tool.